# yum search fails when run as non-root user

Tags: yum, sudo, http-status-code-404, fedora-20

My `yum` has started failing to do search as a non-root user. This was working previously, and then something has been gummed up:

`sudo yum update` works fine, as does `sudo yum search blah`. `yum search blah`, though, generates pages of errors and cannot be interupted.

Can anyone help me understand how to fix this to allow searching with non-root account?

```
robert@...:/etc/yum.repos.d% sudo yum clean metadata    
Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit
Cleaning repos: fedora updates
14 metadata files removed
9 sqlite files removed
0 metadata files removed

% sudo yum clean all                  
Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit
Cleaning repos: fedora updates
Cleaning up everything

% sudo yum update               
Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit
fedora/20/x86_64/metalink                                                      |  33 kB 00:00:00     
fedora                                                                         | 3.8 kB 00:00:00     
updates/20/x86_64/metalink                                                     |  23 kB 00:00:00     
updates                                                                        | 4.9 kB 00:00:00     
(1/4): updates/20/x86_64/primary_db                                            | 9.3 MB 00:00:06     
(2/4): fedora/20/x86_64/group_gz                                               | 394 kB 00:00:06     
(3/4): updates/20/x86_64/group_gz                                              | 394 kB 00:00:06     
(4/4): fedora/20/x86_64/primary_db                                             |  18 MB 00:00:17     
(1/2): updates/20/x86_64/pkgtags                                               | 1.0 MB 00:00:06     
(2/2): updates/20/x86_64/updateinfo                                            | 1.0 MB 00:00:06     
No packages marked for update

% yum search lvm                                  
Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit
http://mirror2.hs-esslingen.de/fedora/linux/updates/20/x86_64/repodata/pkgtags.sqlite.gz: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
http://vesta.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/ftp/pub/Linux/fedora/linux/updates/20/x86_64/repodata/pkgtags.sqlite.gz: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
http://mirror.netcologne.de/fedora/linux/updates/20/x86_64/repodata/pkgtags.sqlite.gz: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
<output curtailed>
```

Comment: it doesn't user problem

Comment: @c4f4t0r: took a while to parse that until I realised 'it' is probably yum, 'doesnt' refers to searching as a non-root user, and you're suggesting it's just my using of the tool that's wrong. I'm afraid that's not true: I can quite happily do `yum search` as non-root on my other systems, and was able to do it on this system until yesterday.

Comment: Are you using a proxy server on your network?

Comment: @Michael, it's running on a VirtualBox with the default network settings - NAT. I haven't suspected that, though, because so is my other linux install, which works fine. Anything particular you suspect? I'd be surprised if a proxy would respond differently depending on the login credentials used to initiate the request.

Answer (score 0):

try installing following package (as root):

`sudo yum install yum-plugin-fastestmirror`

if that won't help, try following

[Yum and RPM database corruption - FedoraForum.org](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=282193)

Comment: Same problem, I'm afraid.

Comment: Followed the first quoted advice in that link (sudo yum clean all NEXT
sudo rm -f /var/lib/rpm/__db.00* NEXT
sudo rpm -vv --rebuilddb NEXT
sudo yum clean all) and it made no difference, unfortunately.